# Proper separate compilation of 2 IRs instructing by ASAN

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, address-sanitizer, libfuzzer

The roots of this question go from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73934768/11273035).

As the title says the question is: "How to do proper separate compilation of 2 IRs instructing by ASAN (OR/AND libfuzzer)?". Before we dive into the actual problem, there is an example that works without separate compilation and the IR layer.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char* sanitize_cookie_path(const char* cookie_path) {
        size_t len;
        char* new_path = strdup(cookie_path);
        if (!new_path) {
            return NULL;
        }
    
    if (new_path[0] == '\"') {
        memmove((void*)new_path, (const void*)(new_path + 1), strlen(new_path));
    }
    if (new_path[strlen(new_path) - 1] == '\"') {
        new_path[strlen(new_path) - 1] = 0x0;
    }

    if (new_path[0] !='/') {
        free(new_path);
        new_path = strdup("/");
        return new_path;
    }

    len = strlen(new_path);
    if (1 < len && new_path[len - 1] == '/') {
        new_path[len - 1] = 0x0;
    }

    return new_path;
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t* data, size_t size) {
    char* string_ = new char[size + 1];
    memcpy(string_, data, size);
    string_[size] = 0x0;

    sanitize_cookie_path(string_);

    delete[] string_;

    return 0;
}
```

**The above code** is compiled with the command below and **works just fine as expected**:

```
$ clang++ -O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,fuzzer -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div sanitize_cookie_path.c -o fuzzer
$ ./fuzzer
=================================================================
==10081==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000004f at pc 0x55ec692f7e51 bp 0x7ffde3767450 sp 0x7ffde3767448
```

**ACTUAL PROBLEM**

Now complicate a task a bit. I have **one piece of code** below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

char* sanitize_cookie_path(const char* cookie_path) {
    size_t len;
    char* new_path = strdup(cookie_path);
    if (!new_path) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (new_path[0] == '\"') {
        memmove((void*)new_path, (const void*)(new_path + 1), strlen(new_path));
    }
    if (new_path[strlen(new_path) - 1] == '\"') {
        new_path[strlen(new_path) - 1] = 0x0;
    }

    if (new_path[0] !='/') {
        free(new_path);
        new_path = strdup("/");
        return new_path;
    }

    len = strlen(new_path);
    if (1 < len && new_path[len - 1] == '/') {
        new_path[len - 1] = 0x0;
    }

    return new_path;
}

// Ditch this part further
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
//
```

The compilation command of the code above:

```
$ clang -O0 -emit-llvm sanitize_cookie_path.c -S -o sanitize_cookie_path.ll
```

**Another piece of code** below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

char* sanitize_cookie_path(const char* cookie_path);

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t* data, size_t size) {
    char* string_ = new char[size + 1];
    memcpy(string_, data, size);
    string_[size] = 0x0;

    sanitize_cookie_path(string_);

    delete[] string_;

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation command of the code above:

```
$ clang -O0 -emit-llvm fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.cc -S -o fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll
```

At this point I tune 2 IRs (resolve C++ name mangling, delete "main" part) so that they fit one another and then I **compile both of them** with the command below and run:

```
$ clang++ -O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,fuzzer -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div sanitize_cookie_path.ll fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll -o fuzzer
$ ./fuzzer
```

The result is not what is expected, to be precise it is:

```
=================================================================
==10186==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
```

, which is not correct in terms of the vulnerability in `sanitize_cookie_path`.

**WHAT I TRIED**

Below I'll list some of the variants of commands I tried to do and their respective output.

**#1**

```
$ clang -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div -emit-llvm sanitize_cookie_path.c -S -o sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div -emit-llvm fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.cc -S -o fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang++ -O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,fuzzer -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div sanitize_cookie_path.ll fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll -o fuzzer
$ ./fuzzer
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==10333==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x01810fff7000 (pc 0x557746efa890 bp 0x7fff83a152a0 sp 0x7fff83a15230 T0)
==10333==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
```

**#2**

```
$ clang -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div -emit-llvm sanitize_cookie_path.c -S -o sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang -O0 -emit-llvm fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.cc -S -o fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang++ -O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,fuzzer -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div sanitize_cookie_path.ll fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll -o fuzzer
$ ./fuzzer
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==10387==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x01810fff7001 (pc 0x561d9ef01d63 bp 0x7ffdd7eb7180 sp 0x7ffdd7eb7030 T0)
==10387==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
```

**#3**

```
$ clang -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div -emit-llvm sanitize_cookie_path.c -S -o sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang -O0 -emit-llvm fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.cc -S -o fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang++ -O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=fuzzer -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div sanitize_cookie_path.ll fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll -o fuzzer
$ ./fuzzer
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**How to attain the same results as in the working example but with separate compilation?**
I would like you to have an exterior look at the problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my question a previous [issue](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1476) in google/sanitizers helped me.

> Asan pass only instruments functions that have sanitize_address
> attribute. It's added to functions only when -fsanitize=address is
> specified. So if you split processing, you may need to it manually
> somehow.

That means that I stick with my original solution

```
$ clang -O0 -emit-llvm sanitize_cookie_path.c -S -o sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang -O0 -emit-llvm fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.cc -S -o fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll
$ clang++ -O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,fuzzer -fsanitize-coverage=trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div sanitize_cookie_path.ll fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll -o fuzzer
```

but before I link `sanitize_cookie_path.ll` and `fuzz_sanitize_cookie_path.ll` (3-rd command), I resolve C++ name mangling, delete `main` function **AND** append to the `sanitize_cookie_path` function on the IR level a [sanitize_address](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/test/Instrumentation/AddressSanitizer/byval-args.ll#L9) attribute.

Now both the working example and separate compilation work the same.